# Removing the unwanted character from date field

Tags: datetime

[image]I am generating the auto label by using the tokens for some field like date of birth and the gender of a person in auto label tab. but after saving the node the date of birth is generating in following format, 2015-08-11 **00:00:00** Male, 
i have chosen the created date format in the manage fields for the DOB field but still its displaying along with 00:00:00, i want to take off this all zeros. please help me on this.

Comment: you can use a php date format for displaying the date.

Comment: i have added the new format, and in manage dispalying choosen that format only, after saving node the dob field is displaying that format only but autolabel where in i user dob field along with gender there its displaying the all unwanted zeros, i am not getting why its?i am searching but no idea.

Comment: its a node field? and where are you displaying the value of that field?

Comment: this field token i am using in auto label tab and generating the auto name using date of birth and gender.

Comment: You need to use [node:changed:short] like this you need to add short after your date field. Will give you dd-mon-yyyy

Comment: @VimalGoradiya: [node:changed:short]  is it a token? after date token do we need to add this one?

Comment: yes, you can add 'short' or 'long' like this https://www.drupal.org/files/images/auto-entity-labels.png

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: @VimalGoradiya: NO,2015-08-11 00:00:00 2015-08-28 17:01 like this showing up, after adding the token next to dob,i have attached screen shot please check with that.

Comment: I think you need to configure your DOB field go and edit remove checkbox hour, minute and second in Date attributes to collect. One another this you can configure your date format at 'admin/config/regional/date-time'

Comment: i have  already configured in the DOB field, i mean i have unchecked the hour,min,sec:(:( but its the same, iam just wondering now, i tried with all formats like long,short,medium  but showing the same